# Match year in string (REGEX)

Tags: regex, cfml

I have some data like:

```
10/2015
11/2020
09/2016
01/2014
```

I want to match everything that is > 2014 (in the future) so I try to use REGEX:

```
<cfif Refind("201[5-9]|202[0-9]|203[0-9]", Date) eq 1>
<!--- dosmth --->
</cfif>
```

I tried also:

```
<cfif Refind("201[5-9]$|202[0-9]$|203[0-9]$", Date) eq 1>
<!--- dosmth --->
</cfif>
```

Doesn't match anything. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: If you need verify the string contains a valid month and year, you might consider using list functions like `getToken()` to perform some additional validation. ie Month between 1 and 12 and Year is >= currentYear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

```
<cfif Refind("^[0-9]{2}\/(201[5-9]|202[0-9]|203[0-9])$", Date) eq 1>
```

Comment: Side note, since reFind always return >= 0, you can omit the `eq 1`.